# What is the Cypress equivalent of Protractor's browser.executeScript() function?

Tags: json, typescript, cypress, session-storage

I'm current trying to convert my Protractor tests to Cypress. Trying to convert Protractor's `browser.executeScript()` function to Cypress has always made me hit a wall.

For instance, I have one Protractor function that looks something like this below. This function clicks the button element just in case `this.button.click()` doesn't work.:

```
this.button = element(by.id(button));

clickExactButton(): promise.Promise<void> {
  return browser.executeScript(
    "arguments[0].click();",
    this.button
  );
}
```

How do I make a Cypress equivalent of this `clickExactButton()` function?

I have another Protractor function that returns `browser.executeScript()`. This creates a session storage item called `http_responses` and then it adds all JSON data from `jsonResponse[]` into it.

```
inject(jsonResponses: jsonResponse[]): promise.Promise<unknown> {

  return browser.executeScript((res) => {
    let currentRes = sessionStorage.getItem('http_responses') || '[]';

    currentRes = JSON.parse(currentRes);

    currentRes = res.concat(currentRes);

    sessionStorage.setItem('http_responses', JSON.stringify(currentRes));
  }, jsonResponses);
}
```

A `jsonResponse[]` object looks something like this:

```
export const ExampleData: jsonResponse[] = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Bob',
    department: 'IT'  
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Alice',
    department: 'Sales' 
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'David',
    department: 'InfoSec' 
  }
]
```

How do I make a Cypress equivalent of this `inject()` function?

Comment: Just use `cy.window`, here's an example from the docs using `sessionStorage` specifically: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Commands-to-work-with-sessionStorage.

Comment: I tried using cy.window for the inject() function, but I'm still struggling to make it achieve the same result as the Protractor one.

Comment: Then give a [mre] to illustrate the specific problem.